# Grouping single line addresses with multiple word cities

Tags: regex, regex-group

**EDIT 2**: Solved. I ended up just requiring a comma dilineation between the street and city name. It's good enough for my needs. The final regex I went with is:

`^(\d+) (\S+.+),[ ]?(.+),[ ]?([A-Za-z]{2})[ ]?(\d{5})$` for those curious.

Howdie,
I'm trying to parse addresses entered on a single line in the following format:

> 1234 Street Name Unit #225 Harpers Ferry, VA 12345
>
> 5547 Street Name City Name, WY 12345
>
> 9958 Street Name Apt 25 New York, NY 12345

**EDIT**: Changed the second example to be more representative of the data sets I'm working with and added a third example of a possible input.

and I'm having trouble dealing with the possibility of two word cities as seen in these examples.
My naive implementation is

`(?<Building>\b\d+)\s(?<Street>.+)(?<City>\b.+),\s(?<State>.{2})\s(?<Zip>\d{5}\b)`

which appears to work provided the city only contains one word. However using the first example it would return the following results:

> Building: 1234
>
> Street: Street Name Unit #225 Harpers
>
> City: Ferry
>
> State: VA
>
> Zip: 12345

Is there any way to cover this case without an additional delimiter at the end of the street and/or unit name?

Comment: You could get a list of cities for each state abbrev, match the state first, use the list of cities for that state. Then you can match the street since you would then know 2 out of 3.

Comment: @sln That's an option. A bit messier than I was hoping for, but it is what it is. Thanks!

Comment: I would say it is really the only option. Without hard knowledge of city names, there can be no real way to do this that you will feel confident of in the end.  @CarySwoveland regex of 198 Wyoming cities in descending order. Size 2k compressed. Source [Wyoming Cities](https://www.alphalists.com/list/alphabetical-list-wyoming-cities) , regex https://pastebin.com/pqCd61LZ. The idea is match the state abbreviation, get the regex of the cities of that state, match the town/city, the remainder is the street numbers.

Comment: @sln You didn't have to go to all that trouble! I appreciate it though!

Comment: Was just an example. I just cut'n pasted the list into my software then posted on pastebin. https://regex101.com/r/z8eZN4/1

Comment: The other option is to make a regex of just 2 or more word cities in the entire US. Put those at the top of the list with a trailing `or` one word `\b\w+\b` for singles. This way you don't have to worry about individual states cities. Many options for you.

Comment: @sln, I understand your suggestion, and think it's a good one, but my point is that there will be lots of exceptions, such as New York City (New York), Salt Lake (Salt Lake City), Fox Farm College (Fox Farm-College), Hill View Hts. (Hill View Heights), and so on.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Each one is a separate line item variant that can be matched `(?i)\b(?:(?:salt[ ]lake|new[ ]york)(?:[ ]city)?|hill[ ]view[ ]h(?:eigh)?ts|fox[ ]farm[ \-]college)\b` each is distinctive. Its the software that does this, not me. Although I am the author.

Comment: Its a hard thing to separate street, city, state on a single line though. The post office has software that might do this but you have to pay for a service I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
(?<Building>\b\d+)\s(?<Street>.*(?:#\d+|No Unit Number))\s(?<City>\b.+),\s(?<State>.{2})\s(?<Zip>\d{5}\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWxwiQ/1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this fails as it's looking specifically for "No Unit Number". I should have clarified I just put that in there as an example of a street address without a unit number, but my cases won't specifically state that. I updated OP to be more clear.

Comment: @Zaq If you don't have a set of possible separators for distinguish the street name from the city name, in some cases this task can be impossible even for a human. Then how do you expect to solve it with a regular expression?

Comment: That's fair. You don't know what you don't know so it never hurts to ask. I've been thinking about this problem for a while and came here as a last resort as I came to the same conclusion. This probably isn't solvable the way I'd like it to be. Thanks for the help anyway! I'll mark your post as the answer for now.

Comment: Precisely, you're the domain expert, so it's your job to find a valid heuristic for separating address and city name. This cannot be done by people who don't know what you're exactly working with.

Comment: yessir. I just modified my input validation to require a comma to delineate between the end of the street address and the beginning of the city. It's good enough for what I need. I was hoping to avoid requiring address to be entered in a non-standard format. Life goes on.